# How to set sessions accessible to all browsers in the computer

Tags: php, session

I believe that sessions are stored in the server and cookies are stored in the browser. I'm using the function below to create a session:

```
function create_session($username, $ip){
    global $strings;
    $unique_id = $strings->get_unique_id($username, $ip);
    $_SESSION['log_users'][] = array('username'=>$username, 'uid'=>$unique_id);

}
```

But when I tried to output the session in another browser, I didn't see anything:

```
print_r($_SESSION['log_users']);
```

I can only see it when inside the same browser where the session is created. Is this how its supposed to work? What do I do so that the session created in one browser can also be seen in another browser?

I've already auto-started session on every page using php.ini. If you need more details then please tell me, thanks.

Comment: Write your own cross-OS/cross-browser virus and promote it to users :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different browsers don't share cookie information, so you would need to start a new session in each browser.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to check whether a user is already logged in or not.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: You cannot do that

Long answer: you have already answered to yourself by saying "I believe that sessions are stored in the server and cookies are stored in the browser"